# why nutch index to a wrong solr collection even though set solr.server.url parameter?

Tags: solr, nutch

integrate nutch 1.15 with solr8.0, but when i use the following command

```
nutch/bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://192.168.199.109:8983/solr/csdn -s ./csdn-seed/ ./data/csdn 1
```

to index crawled data from nutch to solr it throw out the exception in hadoop.log

```
2019-03-23 02:03:07,491 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1877827743_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/nutch/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/nutch/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

but actually, i set solr.server.url to **/solr/csdn** isn't it? but why it told me that it is indexing to **/solr/nutch**?

Answer (score 1):

The way indexer plugins are configured has changed with Nutch 1.15: all indexer plugins are now configured in a single XML file (conf/index-writers.xml), setting or overwriting configuration parameters via Nutch properties is not possible anymore.
See https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexWriters how to configure the Solr server URL. This breaking change was necessary to allow multiple indexers of the same type, e.g. multiple Solr instances.